# Libgdx Scaling Action with Keeping The Center Position

Tags: libgdx

I'm creating a pop out action effect on a window after I click on some button in LibGdx.

May I know, Is there any methods available to scale the actor, in a way that keeping its center position at the center (scales in both direction of x and also both direction of y)?

`addAction(sequence(scaleTo(1.3f,1.3f,0.2f),scaleTo(1f,1f,0.2f)));`

This is the basic scaling method I used.

↑

O →

But I want something like this:

......↑

← O →

......↓

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set actor's origin to its center. **First** set the size, and then call:

```
actor.setOrigin(Align.center);
```

Note, that if your actor is a `Table` (and classes like `Button`, `ImageButton` extend `Table`), then you need to call:

```
actor.setTransform(true); // But keep in mind that has a performance impact "because {@link Batch#flush()} must be done before and after the transform"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, as he wants to do it in a sequence. How can this be done in a sequence?

Comment: @Grisgram Please, read the question more carefully. The OP already does it in a sequence, he just wanted to know how to keep the actor's center in place when scaling.